# Combine different rows in a chart as one value (google sheets)

Tags: google-sheets

For a project I need to show how many hours have been worked by teams on days. The chart needs to contain the days of the week. Monday to Sunday. A day can have multiple rows because the location can differ and a team is full when two employees have registered to work. When full a new row will be created with the same day. My challenge is to show the amount of hours in a chart as one day per weekday instead of showing multiple days with the corresponding working hours. There is no option to manually calculate all the total working hours per day. Is there an other option available to combine the output of the same days? For example: monday monday monday (3 rows) need to be shown as one in the chart.

Thank you for helping!

Answer (score 1):

- Click on Inset -> Chart. Click on chart and new menu will pop-up right of screen. Here you can select type of chart and customize it according to your requirements.

Comment: Thank you, I found the option aggregate to count the different days as one! Is there also an option / formula that can calculate the input of sheet1 + sheet2 as a total without creating a new calculation? The graph / chart needs to handle this. I know that I can add multiple series but they are been shown as different candles in the chart.

Comment: Yeeey! I am happy that it helped you.